# How to set path for gwt upload on ubuntu server

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, gwtupload

I'm using GWT widget to upload my files, I'd like to upload them under tomcat folder on Ubuntu server, so I need to set the param value for this piece of code in web.xml:

```
<context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
    <param-value>
         ...
     </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

If I try to set `http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080/var/lib/tomcat7`it returns `UploadActionException` and `e.getMessage()="http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080//var//lib//tomcat7"`.
It seems that Eclipse try to search this path in my Window filesystem. Any ideas to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your servlet configuration? which servlet class are you using?

Comment: I used this tutorial [link]http://simplygwt.blogspot.it/2011/09/gwt-upload.html @ManoloCarrascoMoñino

Comment: Can you post the code of your `executeAction` implementation where you save the files somwhere, and the code which you want to use to get those files back?

Comment: Thank you @ManoloCarrascoMoñino I have solved, the problem was that I have no permission under tomcat folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8080/var/lib/tomcat7 is not the same thing as /var/lib/tomcat7 on your server.
To use that as the upload directory put this init-param in your upload servlet declaration in web.xml

```
<context-param> 
    <description>Upload Directory</description> 
    <param-name>upload-directory</param-name> 
    <param-value>/var/lib/tomcat7</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

and then in the upload servlet build a path string starting with

```
String dirPath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("upload-directory");
```

then write the FileItem to a file like this

```
File file = new File( dirPath + "/" + fileItem.getName());
fileItem.write(file);
```

All of this would require the whole directory /var/lib/tomcat7 to be writable by whatever user tomcat is running under which is a bad idea. But there you have it.

Comment: If I use */var/lib/tomcat7*, it creates the folders under C://var/lib/tomcat7 in my Window file system. Tomcat is on another ip unbuntu server and not on my pc.

Comment: Thanks @bhowden, I had no permission under this folder and it wasa bad idea to write there! Anyway the problem was also that from window the path was wrong an it runs only when the webapp was deployed under ubuntu.